# Ordering table by column number in case when statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to order table with column number in case when statement?
Here is the code

```
;WITH
    Table1 AS (....),
    Table2 AS (....)

INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT TOP 50 
    one.id,
    one.sales,
    two.count,
    one.sales * two.count as 'Volume %'        
FROM Table1 one,
INNER JOIN Table2 two on one.id = two.id
ORDER BY 
    CASE  @order
        WHEN 1 THEN 
            7             ---Column number here since [Volume %] giving me an error
        WHEN 2 THEN
            10            ---Column number
        END
    DESC
```

Comment: Any reason for not using column name?

Comment: @Sami tried but giving me an error saying `invalid column name`

Comment: You can order by the column number since the number is in the range, so if you have 3 columns and you order by 4, that will throw an error because there is no 4 columns. Also there is no need to use CASE just `ORDER BY (SELECT @Variable)`

Comment: CASE is an expression, it is used to return a value. You are trying to use this to control logic which is can't do. And don't order by ordinal position, it is highly prone to error if your query every changes. Do you need to insert to control the value of identity? If not then adding order to your insert is pointless because a table is an unordered set.

Comment: There are only four columns... `7` or `10` are out of range, aren't they?

Comment: Use a second CTE to name the columns you want.

Comment: @TheImpaler this code is just an example. In my actual code i have more than 10 cols

Comment: @TabAlleman strange, I am doing by `[Volume %]` and it is throwing error

Comment: @SeanLange I am trying to add only top 50 records by `Volume %` in descending order to temp table

Comment: @AntihypeBird you're right, it works in a straight `ORDER BY`, but errors in the `ORDER BY CASE...`

Comment: From [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): _order_by_expression_ Specifies a column or expression on which to sort the query result set. A sort column can be specified as a name or column alias, or **a nonnegative integer** representing the position of the column in the select list. (Emphasis mine.) I take that to mean that a general _expression_ will not be treated as an ordinal column number, it must be an explicit integer.

Comment: Aside: The result of a `case` expression must be _one_ datatype. If your sorting columns are different datatypes then they will need to be converted, implicitly or explicitly, to a single common datatype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done some testing and learned that while a straight ORDER BY can reference column aliases (even those with space characters), a CASE expression in an ORDER BY cannot.   I've never seen this documented anywhere, but I have tested it myself.

It doesn't matter that you have a special character in your alias.  If you had only done:

```
one.sales * two.count as Volume
```

You would still get an error with:

```
  ORDER BY CASE @order
   WHEN 1 THEN Volume
```

And I suspect that's the same reason why you can't use column numbers.

My suggestion as a sure-fire way to fix this is:

```
  ORDER BY CASE @order
   WHEN 1 THEN  one.sales * two.count
```

Comment: I was thinking about this. I dont know why `order by` works like that. I will accept your answer since it gives explanation. Another problem that I have several columns being calculated and there I am using `case` statement too. If I add those in order query, it will be a big mess. I created another temp table where I am inserting top 50 from the table I am generating without ordering. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Well the first level "why" is because having a CASE expression in the ORDER BY causes the parser to determine the ORDER BY **before** Aliases are assigned, while a plain ORDER BY gets parsed **after** aliases are assigned.   The second level, why does the parser do it this way?   No clue.

Comment: And the weird thing is I was not able to find any question similar to this. Wondering how no one had a problem like this. Since I started `sql`ing just a year ago.

Comment: @TabAlleman There is documentation re: column aliases in `order by` expressions. I've added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54224347/92546) with the details.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned in a comment that you're *trying to add only top 50 records by Volume % in descending order to temp table*, you can do something like this:

```
;WITH
    Table1 AS (....),
    Table2 AS (....)

INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT TOP 50 
    one.id,
    one.sales,
    two.count,
    one.sales * two.count as 'Volume %'        
FROM Table1 one,
INNER JOIN Table2 two on one.id = two.id
ORDER BY [Volume %] DESC
```

Comment: Are you sure a column alias `Volume %` is available for the `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: Yes, but it needs to be in brackets (`[Volume %]`)

Comment: You forgot that I have a variable that changes. @Order

Comment: Yeah this totally disregards the need to order by different columns based on the `@order` parameter.

Comment: The reason I disregarded `@order` is because OP commented that "I am trying to add only top 50 records by Volume % in descending order to temp table" and there's only one way to sort `[Volume %]`.

Answer (score 1):

From the the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments) for `ORDER BY`:

> If the ORDER BY clause references a column alias from the select list,
>   the column alias **must be used standalone, and not as a part of some
>   expression** in ORDER BY clause...

A column *name*, not *alias* may be used in an expression, e.g. `case`.

Additionally:

> *order_by_expression*
>
> Specifies a column or expression on which to sort
>   the query result set. A sort column can be specified as a name or
>   column alias, or **a nonnegative integer** representing the position of
>   the column in the select list.

That means that if you `order by 1` the order will be determined by the first column in the select list. Using an expression, e.g. `order by Length * 0 + 1`, will not order by the first column even though the expression happens to evaluate to `1`.

A common technique to move NULL values after others is:

```
select Sample
  from Samples
  order by case when Sample is NULL then 1 else 0 end, Sample;
```

You wouldn't want that `case` expression to select a column by position.

Aside: I would argue that the parser has a bug: `order by 1` correctly orders by the first result column. Using the expression `order by ( 1 )` also orders by the first result column but should generate the same error as `order by 1 + 0`: "A constant expression was encountered in the ORDER BY list, position 1."

It may be part of a pattern of sloppy parsing of simple expressions: [SELECT INTO with IDENTITY column in expression is handled inconsistently](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32905954-select-into-with-identity-column-in-expression-is).

Answer (score 0):

if they are numbers you could try

```
  ....
  ORDER BY 
(CASE WHEN @ORDER = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) * col1 + (CASE WHEN @ORDER = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) * col2
DESC
```

or some sort of similar hack for strings even

have you tried

```
SELECT TOP 50 
    one.id,
    one.sales,
    two.count,
    one.sales * two.count as 'Volume %'        
FROM Table1 one,
INNER JOIN Table2 two on one.id = two.id
ORDER BY 
    CASE  @order
        WHEN 1 THEN 
            one.sales * two.count            ---Column number here since [Volume %] giving me an error
        WHEN 2 THEN
            two.count           ---Column number
        END
    DESC
```

you can't use your calculated renamed field can you?  Unless you use a sub-query