# Oracle order by query using select case

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sql-order-by, case-when

in Oracle Live SQL i was trying to use simple order by sql using select (case when) query

[image: select * from tt order by 1]

[image: select * from tt order by (select (case when 1=1 then 1 else 2 end) from dual]

i tried to get to same result select * from tt order by 1

replace 1 with (select (case when 1=1 then 1 else 2 end) from dual)

but two result completely different.

i want table ordered by column 1 however the query using select case when query doesn't sort by column 1.

I don't know why and want to know how this query works in oracle db

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54133093/ordering-table-by-column-number-in-case-when-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare

```
   ... 
   order by 2
```

and

```
   ... 
   order by 1+1
```

At "compile" time the first `2` is an integer constant so it is a position of the column, the db engine sorts by the specified column. The second `1+1` is an integer expression and the db engine sorts by this value '2'. Same, `(select (case when 1=1 then 1 else 2 end) from dual)` is an expression, not a column specification.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify a number in the `ORDER BY` clause, Oracle will sort by that column of the resulting select. As an example, `ORDER BY 1,2` will sort by the first column, then the second column. If there is no second column, then you will get an error.

In the `ORDER BY` of the outermost query, there is essentially no sorting happening in your query because `1` is always returned from your subquery. This is sorting by the value `1` and not the first column.

If you explain the logic you are hoping to achieve, then we may be able to assist, but that is what is happening with your existing queries.

Comment: based on what logic? The case statement in your example will not sort by anything.

Comment: If you have sample data and the output you are trying to achieve with that output, please share both in a text format (not images)

Comment: i try to get to same result order by 1 using case when query
so first, i used select query after order by expecting return 1
and with that result finally i want to get select * from tt order by 1
why this query doens't sort by column 1??

Comment: That's just how oracle works. If you explain the logic you are trying to achieve with some sample data, then perhaps others can assist.